# Javascript multiple fetch calls inside a Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to parse responses back from the following fetch api calls. I am able to display the response as a string, but I would like to get specific properties from the json blob and I am struggling to do so. I am not sure how to access the json object properties inside the Response Object.

This is for a cloudflare worker using ES6.

The Json structure is here: [json response](https://api.cloudflare.com/#health-checks-health-check-details)

```
{
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": [],
  "result": {
    "id": "699d98642c564d2e855e9661899b7252",
    "created_on": "2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z",
    "modified_on": "2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z",
    "name": "server-1",
    "description": "Health check for www.example.com",
    "suspended": false,
    "notification": {
      "suspended": false,
      "email_addresses": [
        "alert@example.com",
        "oncall@example.com"
      ],
      "trigger": "FAIL"
    },
    "check_regions": [
      "WEU",
      "ENAM"
    ],
    "type": "HTTPS",
    "consecutive_successes": 1,
    "consecutive_fails": 1,
    "http_config": {
      "method": "GET",
      "port": 80,
      "path": "/health",
      "expected_codes": [
        "2xx",
        "302"
      ],
      "expected_body": "success",
      "follow_redirects": false,
      "allow_insecure": false,
      "header": {
        "Host": [
          "example.com"
        ],
        "X-App-ID": [
          "abc123"
        ]
      }
    },
    "tcp_config": {
      "method": "connection_established",
      "port": 80
    },
    "timeout": 5,
    "retries": 2,
    "interval": 60,
    "address": "www.example.com",
    "status": "healthy",
    "failure_reason": ""
  }
}
```

```
const fw1aUrl = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<>/healthchecks/<>"
const fw1bUrl = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<>/healthchecks/<>"
let temp = {}

async function handleRequest() {
  
  const init = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "X-AUTH-EMAIL": CLOUDFLARE_API_EMAIL,
      "X-AUTH-KEY": CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY,
    },
  }
  const [fw1aResponse, fw1bResponse] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(fw1aUrl,init),
    fetch(fw1bUrl,init)
  ]);

  const fw1aresult = await fw1aResponse.json()
  const fw1bresult = await fw1bResponse.json()
  temp.fw1a = await fw1aresult
  temp.fw1b =await  fw1bresult
  const jsonobj = await JSON.parse(temp)
  console.log(jsonobj)
  return jsonobj
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  const obj = handleRequest()
  console.log(obj.fw1a.result)
  console.log(obj.fw1b.result)
  return event.respondWith(new Response("hello"))
})
})
```

Comment: Where in that code are you trying to "*access specific properties from the json*"?

Comment: updated the code to show where i am accessing im having trouble parsing the returned promise obj from handlerequest() .

Comment: `await JSON.parse(temp)` doesn't make sense - `JSON.parse` doesn't return a promise, and  `temp` is an object not a json string. And in `const obj = handleRequest()`, you're not `await`ing the promise that it returns.